# where is the sim_access_rules.proto file which is mentioned in the Android emulator help message?

Tags: android, android-emulator

If, from the root of the Android SDK, I issue this command:

```
tools/emulator -help-sim-access-rules-file
```

I get the following message:

> Textproto configuration file for overriding SIM access rules (see
> sim_access_rules.proto for structure)...

Where can I find this `sim_access_rules.proto` file?  Or if sim_access_rules.proto is not publicly accessible, what is the proper format for the sim access rules configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no sim access rules file in the [Android source repo](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/),  or at https://android.googlesource.com/.
The [emulator command line docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) make no mention of the sim-access-rules-file argument.  I think you can assume this is an option meant for internal use only.

Answer (score 0):

Secure Element access control is used in addition to existing protection mechanisms (such as permissions or security OS policy limiting access to sensitive APIs). The access control is designed to prevent unauthorized access to resources in the Secure Elements and typically to prevent denial of services attacks (PIN blocking, selection of non multi-selectable applets, etc.).

Find details of SIM access rules here along with data structure: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc

Find detailed specifications here: https://globalplatform.org/specs-library/secure-element-access-control-v1-1/#

Comment: Thanks, but while https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc provides information about the structure of rules on the UICC, it does not define the structure of the textproto file to be provided to the emulator.

Comment: @duggulous text.proto file is plaintext file in which you add a message for each data structure you want to serialize, then specify a name and a type for each field. check this link https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: so what are the fields that should go into the sim-access-rules-file, and what are their names & types?  Can you provide an example file?

Comment: The file is to be given by you to the emulator. structure is given. Your question is answered. For further questions on fields and names and types and sample initiate a new question. Keep your question brief. Let us not make this a "tell me more thread".

Comment: The file is not given by the emulator.  The user must supply the file.  The file  is presumably _related_ to the ARF file in the UICC spec, but there could be any number of ways to define a protocol buffer representation of that information, just as there could be any number of ways to represent it in XML or JSON.  We need access to sim_access_rules.proto to know the exact format the emulator is expecting.  The question is not yet answered.